# how can I use repeatinterval every 10 minutes ??

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uilocalnotification

Is there anyway to set local notification repeatinterval every 10 min.

I try to use

```
localnotification.repeatInterval = NSMinuteCalendarUnit*3;
```

and

```
localNotif.repeatInterval = 640;
```

and it don't work.

So could you guide me please. : )

Comment: Please check out the answers and mark it as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you cannot do so.

I had asked similar question previously if you would like to refer to that question.

Here is the link

[How to set Local Notification repeat interval to custom time interval?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4363847/how-to-set-local-notification-repeat-interval-to-custom-time-interval)

Hope this helps you.

Answer (score 3):

as Mundi said the repeatInterval has to be `NSCalendarUnit` and can only contain: `NSWeekCalendarUnit`,  `NSMonthCalendarUnit`,  `NSDayCalendarUnit`, `NSHourCalendarUnit`,..

So the get an notification every 10 min. Use 6 notification that repeat ever hour and set 10 minutes between the notifications.

Answer (score 0):

The `NSTimeInterval` is in seconds, so ten minutes would be `600.0`, not `640`.

`NSMinutesCalenderUnit` has an arbitrarily defined value and does NOT contain the number of seconds per minute.

Did you check that you schedule the Notification properly with `scheduleLocalNotification:` and that you implemented `application:didReceiveLocalNotification:` in your AppDelegate?

Answer (score -1):

Wouldn'T you have to shedule your notification aswell? Like so

[[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:localNotification];