# How to repeat local notification for custom time interval

Tags: iphone, uilocalnotification

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to set Local Notification repeat interval to custom time interval?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4363847/how-to-set-local-notification-repeat-interval-to-custom-time-interval)

I want to repeat local notification for custom time interval(like 2 hours ,3 hours).

I know how to use repeatInterval for local notification. but by using that i can i can repeat notification for hour ,day ,week .

I want to repeat interval for random hours .

Comment: see this :[How to set Local Notification repeat interval to custom time interval?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5131912/1126111)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do custom intervals. But what you can is create a loop to add `UILocalNotification` after a custom interval for a given time.

You always need to remove all notifications before and then readd them, or your users will get each notification x times.

The problem with this is a) it's not performance-friendly and b) if you add custom intervals for the next 2 weeks the user is forced to open your app to recreate the notifications.

**UPDATE:**

> Each application on a device is limited to the soonest-firing 64 scheduled local notifications. The operating system discards notifications that exceed this limit. It considers a recurring notification to be a single notification.