# iPhone : Daily local notifications

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, notifications, uilocalnotification

I am trying to implement local notification

This is what I have set

```
    // Current date
    NSDate *date = [NSDate date]; 

    // Add one minute to the current time
    NSDate *dateToFire = [date dateByAddingTimeInterval:20];

    // Set the fire date/time
    [localNotification setFireDate:dateToFire];
    [localNotification setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone]];
```

Instead of 20, I want to put a fixed time(daily)to start push.

For ex:I want to push notification pop up at every 6:00AM.

How can do that ?

Thanks

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You just need to properly create a `NSDate` object to be your fire date (time).  Instead of using `[NSDate dateByAddingTimeInterval: 20]`, use something like this:

```
NSCalendar *calendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
NSDateComponents *components = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];
[components setDay: 3];
[components setMonth: 7];
[components setYear: 2012];
[components setHour: 6];
[components setMinute: 0];
[components setSecond: 0];
[calendar setTimeZone: [NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone]];
NSDate *dateToFire = [calendar dateFromComponents:components];
```

[Here are the Apple NSDateComponents API docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDateComponents_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

And then when you add the date to the notification, set the repeat interval to one day:

```
[localNotification setFireDate: dateToFire];
[localNotification setTimeZone: [NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone]];
[localNotification setRepeatInterval: kCFCalendarUnitDay];
```

As with all date related code, make sure to test how this works during the switch to daylight savings time, if your time zone uses daylight savings time.

Comment: on console i tried out to find the fire date,which is "2012-07-03 00:30:00 +0000"  i am not sure, will this fire everyday?

Comment: @iscavengers, It will fire every day if you set the repeat interval to `kCFCalendarUnitDay`, as I showed in the code above

Comment: how this will be translated to SWIFT?

Comment: @YestayMuratov, this is an old question. I'd recommend asking a new question [with the Ask button](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask), specifying that you want answers for Swift.  Thanks.

Comment: What to do if i wants to fire it everyday with 3 Different times ?

Answer (score 3):

I guess what you need is **NSDayCalendarUnit**.

You can check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4363847/how-to-set-local-notification-repeat-interval-to-custom-time-interval) answer. And [here](http://useyourloaf.com/blog/2010/09/13/repeating-an-ios-local-notification.html) is another tutorial worth reading.

Answer (score 1):

```
 NSDate *alertTime = [[NSDate date] dateByAddingTimeInterval:10];
    UIApplication* app = [UIApplication sharedApplication];

    UILocalNotification* notifyAlarm = [[[UILocalNotification alloc] init] autorelease];
    if (notifyAlarm)
    {
        notifyAlarm.fireDate = alertTime;
        notifyAlarm.timeZone = [NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone];
        notifyAlarm.repeatInterval = 0;
        notifyAlarm.soundName = @"Glass.aiff";
        notifyAlarm.alertBody = @"Staff meeting in 30 minutes";

        [app scheduleLocalNotification:notifyAlarm];
    }
```