# ios 7 multiple alarm like, periodic audio alerts in background mode

Tags: background, notifications, ios7, multitasking

I am developing a fitness timer for iOS iphone. I want to keep playing audio alerts every x seconds in the background. There can be up to 10 minutes between alerts. (i could live with 5 minutes between alerts). How do you do this in the background? Not nessasary code specifically but i mean how, without application suspending. I mean, localnotifications are limited to 64 messages at a time. 64 messages is not enough at all. I ”round ”  has 3 notifications that should be played. A go alert, a rest alert and a warning alert before the rest alert.

I could repeat these notifications because really i only have 3 different alerts and the user is not changing the time interval in the background, however with local notifications you cant  select specific repeated alert times of for instance 2 minutes and 5 seconds.

Making a background nstimer to run all the time, to manage when to alert the user with a sound, would be a good solution. However now with ios 7 u cant keep a background thread alive for more then 3 minutes (10 minutes before).

How can apps like ”round timer” do this in the background and for an unlimited time?? I need the approved apple directions of doing this? I just need to know what direction i should be going.

EDIT - this an example of the app im talking about that runs in background. It doenst do localnotifications. Round timer - https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/round-timer-for-fitness-workouts/id376965029?mt=8

Comment: Did you find an answer? I'm looking for the same thing. Maybe background mode of 'audio' is the right direction.

Comment: Nope not really. i used ui localnotifications even tho its limited

Answer (score 0):

There is a property in the `UILocalNotification` class called `repeatInterval`, you can use this to create repeated alarms.

See [an example in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13156731/361247).

Comment: like i wrote in the topic ive already tried this.. u cant choose custom repeat times with it so its useless.

Comment: reference to what i am saying. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4363847/how-to-set-local-notification-repeat-interval-to-custom-time-interval