# Impliment local notification for specific day in ios7

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7

I have two table view both has different `NSMutableArray` with dictionary at every index.dictionary has a date field in NSString format. Now my problem is when user set time with picker view than every day he got `local notification` at the same time if record available for that day.
I have no idea how to implement this please help me..
Thank you

Comment: so you want to implement simple local notification for that specific date string?

Answer (score 0):

In your case you need to set `fireDate` its is date/time on which your notification will be arrive and also set `repeatInterval` it's describe repetition of your notification. Here you need to set `kCFCalendarUnitDay` because you want to repeat notification daily.

> **REPEAT UNIT:**
>
> NSEraCalendarUnit
> NSYearCalendarUnit
> NSMonthCalendarUnit
> NSDayCalendarUnit
> NSHourCalendarUnit
> NSMinuteCalendarUnit
> NSSecondCalendarUnit
> NSWeekCalendarUnit
> NSWeekdayCalendarUnit
> NSWeekdayOrdinalCalendarUnit
> NSQuarterCalendarUnit

For more information there are some SO's question.

[Repeat UILocalNotification daily at 5 pm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13156166/repeat-uilocalnotification-daily-at-5-pm)
[iPhone : Daily local notifications](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11303413/iphone-daily-local-notifications)
http://useyourloaf.com/blog/2010/09/13/repeating-an-ios-local-notification.html

Answer (score 0):

In AppDelegate.m

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
  [launchOptions valueForKey:UIApplicationLaunchOptionsLocalNotificationKey];
  return YES;
 }

-(void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveLocalNotification:(UILocalNotification *)notification 
{    
  UIAlertView *notificationAlert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Notification"    message:@"This local notification" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
  [notificationAlert show];
   // NSLog(@"didReceiveLocalNotification");
}
```

This code in .m file to your ViewController :

```
-(IBAction)startLocalNotification 
{  
  NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
  [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"h:mm a"];
  NSDate *dateFromString = [[NSDate alloc] init];
  dateFromString = [dateFormatter dateFromString:timeStr];

  NSLog(@"startLocalNotification");    
  UILocalNotification *notification = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
  notification.fireDate = dateFromString;
  notification.repeatInterval = NSDayCalendarUnit;
  notification.alertBody = @"This is local notification!";
  notification.timeZone = [NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone];
  notification.soundName = UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName;
  notification.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 10;
  [[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:notification];    
}
```