# How to fire daily localnotification at specific time in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

I want to get daily notification and for that I have googled and
I got some solution from this [iPhone : Daily local notifications](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11303413/iphone-daily-local-notifications) but I couldn't recognise properly

```
NSCalendar *calendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
NSDateComponents *components = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];
[components setDay: 3];
[components setMonth: 7];
[components setYear: 2012];
[components setHour: 6];
[components setMinute: 0];
[components setSecond: 0];
[calendar setTimeZone: [NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone]];
NSDate *dateToFire = [calendar dateFromComponents:components];
```

Let's say suppose current time is **3:13, and current date is 20-11-2014**
in this I want to set local notification at time of  **3:14, 20-11-2014** can anybody please help me, because I have tried with following things but not working

```
    [components setDay: 20];
    [components setMonth: 11];
    [components setYear: 2014];
    [components setHour: 15];
    [components setMinute: 14];
    [components setSecond: 0];
```

Comment: Get the current date/time, add one day (if before midnight), extract the date components, set the hour to 7 and reset minutes/seconds to 0, and then create a new date object from those date components.  You cannot do it with date components alone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 NSDate *date = [NSDate date];
NSDate *newDate1 = [date dateByAddingTimeInterval:60*60*24];
UILocalNotification *localNotif = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
localNotif.fireDate = newDate1;
localNotif.timeZone = [NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone];
localNotif.alertBody = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"NotificationText"];
localNotif.alertAction = @"View";
localNotif.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 1;
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:localNotif];
```

try this one hope this may help you. Thank you

Comment: Using `60*60*24` is wrong and will lead to subtle errors some of the time.

Comment: i used 60*60*24 for representing total seconds in one day (i.e. 86400 seconds) you can customise according to your requirement :)
and what was that error?

Comment: During daylight saving time changes the number of seconds between X hour today and X hour tomorrow is not 86400 seconds.

Comment: I don't think that much deep. Its just a mathematical calculation thats all. :)

Comment: Yah I know. I just used an example you can edit whatever you like.

Comment: That's not how it works here.  You will be repeatedly downvoted until you correct your answer.

Comment: I am using this same code and it works. And it give daily notification to me. I written this code in - (void)applicationWillResignActive:(UIApplication *)application

Answer (score -1):

```
NSDate* now = [NSDate date] ;
NSDateComponents* tomorrowComponents = [NSDateComponents new] ;
tomorrowComponents.day = 1 ;
NSCalendar* calendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar] ;
NSDate* tomorrow = [calendar dateByAddingComponents:tomorrowComponents toDate:now options:0] ;
NSDateComponents* tomorrowAt7AMComponents = [calendar components:(NSEraCalendarUnit|NSYearCalendarUnit|NSMonthCalendarUnit|NSDayCalendarUnit) fromDate:tomorrow] ;
tomorrowAt7AMComponents.hour = 7 ;
NSDate* tomorrowAt7AM = [calendar dateFromComponents:tomorrowAt7AMComponents] ;
localnotification.fireDate = tomorrowAt7AM;
```

I hope this helps you.

Comment: Don't you need to do something to `tomorrowComponents` before using it?

Comment: I don't see how.  You create an `NSDateComponents` object and use it to create a new date, from *now*, without having set anything in that date components object.

Comment: This is't the answer, and u r mislead others. This isn't a `UILocalNotification`, the @Deepesh V R is the right answer...

Comment: localnotification.fireDate .here the localnotification refers to the UILocalNotification object

Comment: @trojanfoe tomorrowComponents is used to just get a date(tomorrow's) from 'now' from the calendar. it has not been used after that

Comment: But it's not been initialised.  I would expect `tomorrowComponents.day = 1;` before it was used.

Comment: OK so now it's been updated to what I would expect and I will revert my downvote, but why the statement "no need. It works for me.!!" and why was the answer accepted before this edit?

Comment: He didn't ask for how to set local notification. he asked for how to set a date for a local notification. He asked for the date. The answer which is marked correct will fire notification after 24hrs. It will not fire notification at 7am daily.