# swift iOS localNotifications

Tags: ios, swift, notifications

I want to set local notifications for specific times, eg : 04:30 Am Everyday, but i cant figure it out. I am new to iOS development and all localNotifications tutorials just cover fireDate = NSDate()

Thank you!

Comment: Checkout this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11303413/iphone-daily-local-notifications

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code in your function you want to fire local notification:

```
let calendar = NSCalendar(calendarIdentifier: NSCalendarIdentifierGregorian)
let date = NSDate()
let dateComponents = calendar!.components([NSCalendarUnit.Day, NSCalendarUnit.WeekOfMonth, NSCalendarUnit.Month,NSCalendarUnit.Year,NSCalendarUnit.Hour,NSCalendarUnit.Minute], fromDate:date)
dateComponents.hour = 4
dateComponents.minute = 30
let notification = UILocalNotification()
notification.alertAction = "Title"
notification.alertBody = "Fire Fire Fire :v"
notification.repeatInterval = NSCalendarUnit.WeekOfYear
notification.fireDate = calendar.dateFromComponents(dateComponents)
UIApplication.sharedApplication().scheduleLocalNotification(notification)
```

And remember to put this code in your AppDelegate:

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {   
    application.registerUserNotificationSettings(UIUserNotificationSettings(forTypes: [.Sound, .Badge, .Alert], categories: nil))
    return true
  }
```