# UILocalNotification repeat every minute

Tags: iphone, ios, ios5, uilocalnotification, localnotification

I want to send local notification every minute and this is code that I'm using:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] cancelAllLocalNotifications];

    UILocalNotification *notif = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];

    if (notif == nil) {
        return;
    }

    notif.timeZone = [NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone];

    notif.alertBody = @"Test notification!";
    notif.alertAction = @"View";
    notif.soundName = UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName;
    notif.applicationIconBadgeNumber += 1;

    notif.repeatInterval = NSMinuteCalendarUnit;

    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:notif];
```

The notification starts only once and never is repeated. Where I make mistakte?

Comment: visit this one mate:-http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4363847/how-to-set-local-notification-repeat-interval-to-custom-time-interval

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to set a `fireDate` for your notification, otherwise it won't repeat but fire instantly.

> The fire date is interpreted according to the value specified for
>   timeZone. If the specified value is nil or is a date in the past, the
>   notification is delivered immediately.

Comment: ohh ok then give  your Best and Cleaver answer ok i just deleted mine answer be happy  :)

Comment: Thanks this help me. After I add `fireDate` notification works

Comment: @NitinGohel I didn't mean to offend you, but Stackoverflow is not a full quote community. Take some time to understand the question and give a real answer, don't just copy over some unrelated answer.